# Gridview: Wanting to do something based on the end-result of the binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, page-lifecycle

What if I want to do something based on the result of the binding of the gridview...

For example, if zero rows are returned by the binding, I want to set lblMessage.Text on the form as "No records Found"

Based on the page life-cycle, I am not sure where such logic should be placed, or if this is even possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think i can use databound event of the gridview...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution one:**

if all you want is to show some text indicating the grid view is empty you can use `EmptyDataText` property of grid view

Example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="somethingGridView" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No records Found" </asp:GridView>
```

---

**Solution two:**

after calling the data table you can check if it has data in it and then simply hide the grid view and show the label you want 
Example:

```
DataTable dt = dataCallFunction();
if(dt.Rows.Count == 0){
    IdOfGridView.Visible = False;
    IdOfLabel.Visible = True;
}
```

---

These are just two solutions of many you could do.